# Unable to place pokémon into a gym

Tags: pokemon-go

I defeated a gym in *Pokémon Go* and healed my pokémon back up, but I still couldn't put either of my strongest two in there. I could put another pokémon in there. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What are your strongest two?

Answer (score 15):

You can't put pokémon to defend a gym if:

- The pokémon isn't fully healed or revived.
- The pokémon is currently guarding another gym.
- The pokémon is legendary.
- The gym already had that pokémon defending placed by another team member.
- The gym is controlled by your team and under attack.